# Ways to Encrypt and decrypt array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

I am completly new to jquery and client side programing. I am trying to figure out a way of achiving this:

1. On the client side I have a hidden user id/profile id, which I wanna to encrypt, but while manipulating the hidden value, I have to decrypt and perform some operation on it.
2. I have a global array of arrays like below:

   ```
   var users=[{"u_id":"1234", "u_name":"Test"},{"u_id":"12345", "u_name":"Test1"}];
   ```

this array is used by various other compoenets, e.g. when user mouse-over on the profile-id, it will get the details from the above array and display the result to him.

In short, I want to encrypt/decrypt all my global variables inside the script.

any plugin or ways to do will be highly appricated.

Comment: That's not an array of arrays, it's an array of objects

Comment: Searching for `javascript cryptography` leads straight to https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/.

Comment: What exactly is your reason for wanting the encryption? What are you trying to hide, and who are you trying to hide it from?

Comment: You do realize that people running your client side code in their browsers have access to interactive debuggers that can very easily pause, inspect and manipulate everything that your program does right?

Comment: @FelixKling, Thanks for pointing to the link..seems it has what I was looking for. -musefan, I may not be clear to express the exact problem senario, but I want to achieve the below task, on first page load it got all the array or json data and then from that data, it will build html, and then various operation like , updating user information, then user needs to send profileid/user id/sessionkey along with data he is updateing, so other person can easily update from other source who have the keys mentioned above...So looking for a solution where these key information can be in secured way.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to **use server side validation of user actions.** Profile ids etc. do not need to be secret. A user id, say `42`, is just a number, it's nothing secret. The question is: what can a user do knowing that number?! If the answer is that he can simply tell your server to "update user 42's profile to *XYZ*", you are doing it wrong. The server needs to check whether anyone is allowed to change some data or do something and reject that action if he's not.

Comment: @deceze: Yes exactly, the example you have posted, lets say user 42, trying to update his age, basicaly user will see 42 as his profile id when he logsin, and then subsequent call he will make for changes he need to pass sessionkey/apikey along with profile id and data, so basically if you will suggest me how I can manage these sessionkey/apikey, so that user/hacker from outside can't missuse..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @deceze: Yes exactly, the example you have posted, lets say user 42, trying to update his age, basicaly user will see 42 as his profile id when he logsin, and then subsequent call he will make for changes he need to pass sessionkey/apikey along with profile id and data, so basically if you will suggest me how I can manage these sessionkey/apikey, so that user/hacker from outside can't missuse.. – Jayaram Pradhan 1 min ago

It's pretty simple:

1. Require users to be logged in via a regular login mechanism, typically involving a session id. This session identifies the user as securely as it's feasible to do anything securely over the web. Your security focus must be here.
2. Knowing who the user is, you can validate any and all of his actions. If the user requests to change the profile information of some user, check whether he's allowed to do that or not. No API key or anything needed. The server receives a request for change, the server knows who the requesting user is by the session, the server can decide to accept or reject the request.

   - In the concrete case of updating one's own profile, if the user is only allowed to update his profile and his profile alone: there needs to be only one action/URL, when a user POSTs data to that action, the server knows who the user is and updates that user's profile. The user doesn't need to submit a user id of the profile he wants to update, in fact he *can't* submit a user id, only his profile will ever get updated. There's no publicly accessible action that allows him to update anyone else's profile.
3. There is no 3.

Comment: Thank you... The point you have mentioned regarding session id, suppose a application is capable of handeling heigh volume of users, then maintaing the session ID may over kill(I never see it in practical but in theory or from google I got some info regarding this). for that I was thinking  of a key known as API key.....please validate my understanding.

Comment: It's basically the same thing. The session id identifies a user, but gets discarded after the session is over. An API key identifies a user indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you ...I have to dig down little further to check how I effeciently I can manage API key...It will be great if you are giving any ref link which might help me.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption/decryption on the client side is **entirely pointless**. Encryption is used to *hide* something from somebody. For that you need a *secret* (password etc.) that you're not giving to that somebody.

If you want to encrypt and decrypt something on the client, the client will need the secret in order to do the encryption. Therefore, the client has everything it needs to decrypt any encrypted secret. That means any user has everything he needs to decrypt data and can in fact see the process happening (try breakpoints in your browser's Javascript debugger). Therefore, the entire exercise is by definition pointless. It may deter some very unskilled poker-arounder, but anyone with the skill to actually do something with the decrypted data can get it easily.

Comment: Thank you, from your point it makes sense, why I will encrypt, it will make overhead nothing else it can't help me to provide security, I have replied to your comment, any point or suggestion to that wil be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

i know no way to perform this on client side, you can serialize and obfuscate the data (like using base 64 encoding on json string).